# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 : If Directory Does Not Have Files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please assist me with the following scenario. I'm scanning the last two hours of folders and then taking the most recent CSV files and generating a single list.
If both the hours folders contain files, the code below is working as expected. but if any folder does not contain any files, then it is showing "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0"

code :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.language.postfixOps
val hdfsConf = new Configuration();
var path="/user/hdfs/test/input"
var finalFiles = List[String]()
val currentTs = java.time.LocalDateTime.now
val hours=2
var paths = (0 until hours.toInt).map(h => currentTs.minusHours(h))
   .map(ts=>s"${path}/partition_date=${ts.toLocalDate}/hour=${ts.toString.substring(11, 13)}")
.toList

// paths: List[String] = List(/user/hdfs/test/input/partition_date=2022-11-30/hour=19,
// /user/hdfs/test/input/partition_date=2022-11-30/hour=18)

for (eachfolder <- paths) {
var New_Folder_Path: String = eachfolder
var fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
var pathstatus = fs.listStatus(new Path(New_Folder_Path))
var currpathfiles = pathstatus.map(x => Row(x.getPath.toString, x.getModificationTime))
var latestFile = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(currpathfiles)
.map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getLong(1)))
.toDF("FilePath", "ModificationTime")
.filter(col("FilePath")
.like("%.csv%"))
.sort($"ModificationTime".desc)
.select(col("FilePath")).limit(1)
.map(row => row.getString(0)).collectAsList.get(0)

finalFiles = latestFile :: finalFiles
}
```

Erorr:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an issue when trying to obtain the `0`th element from an empty list. You can avoid this by using `List`'s [`headOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#headOption:Option%5BA%5D) method along with [`foreach`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Option.html#foreach%5BU%5D(f:A=%3EU):Unit) on the resulting `Option`.

```scala
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(currpathfiles)
  .map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getLong(1)))
  ...
  .map(row => getString(0))
  .collectAsList.headOption
  .foreach(latestFile =>  finalFiles = latestFile :: finalFiles)
```

Also note that instead of assigning `latestFile` to a var, my implementation just prepends it within the `Option`'s `foreach` to the `finalFiles` list (for each will only act when there exists an element after we call `collectAsList`).